Is Stack Overflow Jobs usable with an adblocker?
I clicked on the link the new banner is showing. It takes me to https://stackoverflow.jobs/?source=so-banner and it loads an animated logo.
That's it.
In my console (Firefox), I see the following calls on page load:

The one that is failing is blocked by uBlock Origin and is:

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://partner-api.jobbio.com/channels/data?domain=stackoverflow.jobs&source=stackoverflow.jobs_index. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.

Does this mean that the new Stack Overflow jobs board is not usable with uBlock Origin (and potentially other ad blockers) enabled?

I can't load the site on Firefox at all, with or without my AdBlocker (AdBlock Ultimate) enabled. Just the loading image, like you state

A jobs board is full ads. It is by design that uBlock keeps you safe and sane.

And I'm not even kidding: Ad blockers currently block the whole site from loading - for now, consider disabling your ad blocker if you want to use the job site

Is Stack Overflow Jobs usable ... No.

yep it breaks with AdBlock Version 6.0.1 ... whitelisting it seem to work

@ThomA Not working at all without an adblocker sounds like a different issue, which you might want to report over on MSE.

I must admit, I'm not bothered enough to, @RyanM . It's not available outside of America (yet?), and even then, I'm unlikely to use it.

It took oddly long, but I loaded the site using Brave.

There is no longer Stack Overflow Jobs. The link named "Jobs" just points to an external website (something called "Indeed") disguised in SO colors and logo.

On Meta Stack Exchange SE Staff posted Known Issues with MVP Stack Overflow Jobs Launch
One of the items is:


Ad blockers currently block the whole site from loading - for now, consider disabling your ad blocker if you want to use the job site


The question does ask for other bug reports as answers (currently 6 and counting) and also states:

... we can get them fixed as soon as possible.

I assume that means within 6 to 8 weeks but it is not clear if that also goes for the ad blocking issue. I wouldn't have high hopes.

Oh...hiding over on MSE. Thanks rene.

Given how much the network is on fire at the moment hiding there might not be the best idea ....
